# OS X Postfix no TLS found

Tags: osx, email, postfix, ssl

I'm working on OSX El Capitan. About week ago everything worked fine, but then I changed my gmail password and now I can't send emails any more.

Additional configuration for `/etc/postfix/main.cf` is:

```
mydomain_fallback = localhost

#Gmail SMTP
relayhost=[smtp.gmail.com]:587
# Enable SASL authentication in the Postfix SMTP client.
smtp_sasl_auth_enable=yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter=plain

# Enable Transport Layer Security (TLS), i.e. SSL.
smtp_use_tls=yes
smtp_tls_security_level=encrypt
tls_random_source=dev:/dev/urandom
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
```

File `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd`:

```
smtp.gmail.com:465 XXXXXXXXX@gmail.com:XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

after editing this file, of course I run the next commands:

```
sudo postfix stop
sudo postfix start
sudo launchctl stop org.postfix.master
sudo launchctl start org.postfix.master
```

When I trying to send simple mail, log show me:

```
Feb 24 14:32:26 Alexs-MBP postfix/postfix-script[13101]: refreshing the Postfix mail system
Feb 24 14:32:26 Alexs-MBP postfix/master[8527]: reload -- version 2.11.0, configuration /etc/postfix
Feb 24 14:32:35 Alexs-MBP postfix/pickup[13124]: 9716B5E1416: uid=501 from=<alex>
Feb 24 14:32:35 Alexs-MBP postfix/cleanup[13125]: 9716B5E1416: message-id=<20160224133235.9716B5E1416@Alexs-MBP.localdomain>
Feb 24 14:32:35 Alexs-MBP postfix/qmgr[13127]: 9716B5E1416: from=<alex@Alexs-MBP.localdomain>, size=355, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 24 14:32:35 Alexs-MBP postfix/qmgr[13127]: 789625E10FF: from=<alex@Alexs-MBP.localdomain>, size=354, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 24 14:32:35 Alexs-MBP postfix/smtp[13128]: warning: connect to private/tlsmgr: Connection refused
Feb 24 14:32:35 Alexs-MBP postfix/smtp[13128]: warning: problem talking to server private/tlsmgr: Connection refused
Feb 24 14:32:36 Alexs-MBP postfix/smtp[13128]: warning: connect to private/tlsmgr: Connection refused
Feb 24 14:32:36 Alexs-MBP postfix/smtp[13128]: warning: problem talking to server private/tlsmgr: Connection refused
Feb 24 14:32:36 Alexs-MBP postfix/smtp[13128]: warning: no entropy for TLS key generation: disabling TLS support
Feb 24 14:32:36 Alexs-MBP postfix/smtp[13129]: warning: connect to private/tlsmgr: Connection refused
Feb 24 14:32:36 Alexs-MBP postfix/smtp[13129]: warning: problem talking to server private/tlsmgr: Connection refused
Feb 24 14:32:36 Alexs-MBP postfix/smtp[13128]: 9716B5E1416: TLS is required, but our TLS engine is unavailable
Feb 24 14:32:36 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Feb 24 14:32:36 Alexs-MBP postfix/smtp[13128]: connect to smtp.gmail.com[2a00:1450:4010:c04::6d]:587: No route to host
Feb 24 14:32:36 Alexs-MBP postfix/smtp[13128]: 9716B5E1416: to=<YYYYYYYY@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=1.3, delays=0.03/1/0.26/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to smtp.gmail.com[2a00:1450:4010:c04::6d]:587: No route to host)
Feb 24 14:32:36 Alexs-MBP postfix/smtp[13128]: warning: connect to private/scache: Connection refused
Feb 24 14:32:37 Alexs-MBP postfix/smtp[13129]: warning: connect to private/tlsmgr: Connection refused
Feb 24 14:32:37 Alexs-MBP postfix/smtp[13129]: warning: problem talking to server private/tlsmgr: Connection refused
Feb 24 14:32:37 Alexs-MBP postfix/smtp[13129]: warning: no entropy for TLS key generation: disabling TLS support
Feb 24 14:32:37 Alexs-MBP postfix/smtp[13128]: warning: connect to private/scache: Connection refused
Feb 24 14:32:37 Alexs-MBP postfix/smtp[13128]: warning: disabling connection caching
Feb 24 14:32:38 Alexs-MBP postfix/smtp[13128]: 789625E10FF: TLS is required, but our TLS engine is unavailable
Feb 24 14:32:38 Alexs-MBP postfix/smtp[13128]: connect to smtp.gmail.com[2a00:1450:4010:c04::6d]:587: No route to host
Feb 24 14:32:38 Alexs-MBP postfix/smtp[13128]: 789625E10FF: to=<XXXXXXXX@gmail.com>, relay=smtp.gmail.com[173.194.71.108]:587, delay=811, delays=808/1.3/1.3/0, dsn=4.7.5, status=deferred (TLS is required, but our TLS engine is unavailable)
```

Explanation:

- `XXXXXXXX@gmail.com` -> my email
- `YYYYYYYY@gmail.com` -> recipient's email
- `Alexs-MBP` -> the name of my MacBook

Comment: As far as I know, you need to rebuild the .db file once you altered the passwd file on which it's based upon. `postmap hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd`

Comment: I already did it.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. The main.cf should look in this way:

```
# SOFT BOUNCE
#
# The soft_bounce parameter provides a limited safety net for
# testing.  When soft_bounce is enabled, mail will remain queued that
# would otherwise bounce. This parameter disables locally-generated
# bounces, and prevents the SMTP server from rejecting mail permanently
# (by changing 5xx replies into 4xx replies). However, soft_bounce
# is no cure for address rewriting mistakes or mail routing mistakes.
#
#soft_bounce = no

# LOCAL PATHNAME INFORMATION
#
# The queue_directory specifies the location of the Postfix queue.
# This is also the root directory of Postfix daemons that run chrooted.
# See the files in examples/chroot-setup for setting up Postfix chroot
# environments on different UNIX systems.
#
queue_directory = /private/var/spool/postfix

# The command_directory parameter specifies the location of all
# postXXX commands.
#
command_directory = /usr/sbin

# The daemon_directory parameter specifies the location of all Postfix
# daemon programs (i.e. programs listed in the master.cf file). This
# directory must be owned by root.
#
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix

# The data_directory parameter specifies the location of Postfix-writable
# data files (caches, random numbers). This directory must be owned
# by the mail_owner account (see below).
#
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix

# QUEUE AND PROCESS OWNERSHIP
#
# The mail_owner parameter specifies the owner of the Postfix queue
# and of most Postfix daemon processes.  Specify the name of a user
# account THAT DOES NOT SHARE ITS USER OR GROUP ID WITH OTHER ACCOUNTS
# AND THAT OWNS NO OTHER FILES OR PROCESSES ON THE SYSTEM.  In
# particular, don't specify nobody or daemon. PLEASE USE A DEDICATED
# USER.
#
mail_owner = _postfix

# The default_privs parameter specifies the default rights used by
# the local delivery agent for delivery to external file or command.
# These rights are used in the absence of a recipient user context.
# DO NOT SPECIFY A PRIVILEGED USER OR THE POSTFIX OWNER.
#
#default_privs = nobody

# INTERNET HOST AND DOMAIN NAMES
# 
# The myhostname parameter specifies the internet hostname of this
# mail system. The default is to use the fully-qualified domain name
# from gethostname(). $myhostname is used as a default value for many
# other configuration parameters.
#
#myhostname = host.domain.tld
#myhostname = virtual.domain.tld

# The mydomain parameter specifies the local internet domain name.
# The default is to use $myhostname minus the first component.
# $mydomain is used as a default value for many other configuration
# parameters.
#
#mydomain = domain.tld

# SENDING MAIL
# 
# The myorigin parameter specifies the domain that locally-posted
# mail appears to come from. The default is to append $myhostname,
# which is fine for small sites.  If you run a domain with multiple
# machines, you should (1) change this to $mydomain and (2) set up
# a domain-wide alias database that aliases each user to
# user@that.users.mailhost.
#
# For the sake of consistency between sender and recipient addresses,
# myorigin also specifies the default domain name that is appended
# to recipient addresses that have no @domain part.
#
#myorigin = $myhostname
#myorigin = $mydomain

# RECEIVING MAIL

# The inet_interfaces parameter specifies the network interface
# addresses that this mail system receives mail on.  By default,
# the software claims all active interfaces on the machine. The
# parameter also controls delivery of mail to user@[ip.address].
#
# See also the proxy_interfaces parameter, for network addresses that
# are forwarded to us via a proxy or network address translator.
#
# Note: you need to stop/start Postfix when this parameter changes.
#
#inet_interfaces = all
#inet_interfaces = $myhostname
#inet_interfaces = $myhostname, localhost

# The proxy_interfaces parameter specifies the network interface
# addresses that this mail system receives mail on by way of a
# proxy or network address translation unit. This setting extends
# the address list specified with the inet_interfaces parameter.
#
# You must specify your proxy/NAT addresses when your system is a
# backup MX host for other domains, otherwise mail delivery loops
# will happen when the primary MX host is down.
#
#proxy_interfaces =
#proxy_interfaces = 1.2.3.4

# The mydestination parameter specifies the list of domains that this
# machine considers itself the final destination for.
#
# These domains are routed to the delivery agent specified with the
# local_transport parameter setting. By default, that is the UNIX
# compatible delivery agent that lookups all recipients in /etc/passwd
# and /etc/aliases or their equivalent.
#
# The default is $myhostname + localhost.$mydomain.  On a mail domain
# gateway, you should also include $mydomain.
#
# Do not specify the names of virtual domains - those domains are
# specified elsewhere (see VIRTUAL_README).
#
# Do not specify the names of domains that this machine is backup MX
# host for. Specify those names via the relay_domains settings for
# the SMTP server, or use permit_mx_backup if you are lazy (see
# STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README).
#
# The local machine is always the final destination for mail addressed
# to user@[the.net.work.address] of an interface that the mail system
# receives mail on (see the inet_interfaces parameter).
#
# Specify a list of host or domain names, /file/name or type:table
# patterns, separated by commas and/or whitespace. A /file/name
# pattern is replaced by its contents; a type:table is matched when
# a name matches a lookup key (the right-hand side is ignored).
# Continue long lines by starting the next line with whitespace.
#
# See also below, section "REJECTING MAIL FOR UNKNOWN LOCAL USERS".
#
#mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
#mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
#mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain,
#   mail.$mydomain, www.$mydomain, ftp.$mydomain

# REJECTING MAIL FOR UNKNOWN LOCAL USERS
#
# The local_recipient_maps parameter specifies optional lookup tables
# with all names or addresses of users that are local with respect
# to $mydestination, $inet_interfaces or $proxy_interfaces.
#
# If this parameter is defined, then the SMTP server will reject
# mail for unknown local users. This parameter is defined by default.
#
# To turn off local recipient checking in the SMTP server, specify
# local_recipient_maps = (i.e. empty).
#
# The default setting assumes that you use the default Postfix local
# delivery agent for local delivery. You need to update the
# local_recipient_maps setting if:
#
# - You define $mydestination domain recipients in files other than
#   /etc/passwd, /etc/aliases, or the $virtual_alias_maps files.
#   For example, you define $mydestination domain recipients in    
#   the $virtual_mailbox_maps files.
#
# - You redefine the local delivery agent in master.cf.
#
# - You redefine the "local_transport" setting in main.cf.
#
# - You use the "luser_relay", "mailbox_transport", or "fallback_transport"
#   feature of the Postfix local delivery agent (see local(8)).
#
# Details are described in the LOCAL_RECIPIENT_README file.
#
# Beware: if the Postfix SMTP server runs chrooted, you probably have
# to access the passwd file via the proxymap service, in order to
# overcome chroot restrictions. The alternative, having a copy of
# the system passwd file in the chroot jail is just not practical.
#
# The right-hand side of the lookup tables is conveniently ignored.
# In the left-hand side, specify a bare username, an @domain.tld
# wild-card, or specify a user@domain.tld address.
# 
#local_recipient_maps = unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps
#local_recipient_maps = proxy:unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps
#local_recipient_maps =

# The unknown_local_recipient_reject_code specifies the SMTP server
# response code when a recipient domain matches $mydestination or
# ${proxy,inet}_interfaces, while $local_recipient_maps is non-empty
# and the recipient address or address local-part is not found.
#
# The default setting is 550 (reject mail) but it is safer to start
# with 450 (try again later) until you are certain that your
# local_recipient_maps settings are OK.
#
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550

# TRUST AND RELAY CONTROL

# The mynetworks parameter specifies the list of "trusted" SMTP
# clients that have more privileges than "strangers".
#
# In particular, "trusted" SMTP clients are allowed to relay mail
# through Postfix.  See the smtpd_recipient_restrictions parameter
# in postconf(5).
#
# You can specify the list of "trusted" network addresses by hand
# or you can let Postfix do it for you (which is the default).
#
# By default (mynetworks_style = subnet), Postfix "trusts" SMTP
# clients in the same IP subnetworks as the local machine.
# On Linux, this does works correctly only with interfaces specified
# with the "ifconfig" command.
# 
# Specify "mynetworks_style = class" when Postfix should "trust" SMTP
# clients in the same IP class A/B/C networks as the local machine.
# Don't do this with a dialup site - it would cause Postfix to "trust"
# your entire provider's network.  Instead, specify an explicit
# mynetworks list by hand, as described below.
#  
# Specify "mynetworks_style = host" when Postfix should "trust"
# only the local machine.
# 
#mynetworks_style = class
#mynetworks_style = subnet
#mynetworks_style = host

# Alternatively, you can specify the mynetworks list by hand, in
# which case Postfix ignores the mynetworks_style setting.
#
# Specify an explicit list of network/netmask patterns, where the
# mask specifies the number of bits in the network part of a host
# address.
#
# You can also specify the absolute pathname of a pattern file instead
# of listing the patterns here. Specify type:table for table-based lookups
# (the value on the table right-hand side is not used).
#
#mynetworks = 168.100.189.0/28, 127.0.0.0/8
#mynetworks = $config_directory/mynetworks
#mynetworks = hash:/etc/postfix/network_table

# The relay_domains parameter restricts what destinations this system will
# relay mail to.  See the smtpd_recipient_restrictions description in
# postconf(5) for detailed information.
#
# By default, Postfix relays mail
# - from "trusted" clients (IP address matches $mynetworks) to any destination,
# - from "untrusted" clients to destinations that match $relay_domains or
#   subdomains thereof, except addresses with sender-specified routing.
# The default relay_domains value is $mydestination.
# 
# In addition to the above, the Postfix SMTP server by default accepts mail
# that Postfix is final destination for:
# - destinations that match $inet_interfaces or $proxy_interfaces,
# - destinations that match $mydestination
# - destinations that match $virtual_alias_domains,
# - destinations that match $virtual_mailbox_domains.
# These destinations do not need to be listed in $relay_domains.
# 
# Specify a list of hosts or domains, /file/name patterns or type:name
# lookup tables, separated by commas and/or whitespace.  Continue
# long lines by starting the next line with whitespace. A file name
# is replaced by its contents; a type:name table is matched when a
# (parent) domain appears as lookup key.
#
# NOTE: Postfix will not automatically forward mail for domains that
# list this system as their primary or backup MX host. See the
# permit_mx_backup restriction description in postconf(5).
#
#relay_domains = $mydestination

# INTERNET OR INTRANET

# The relayhost parameter specifies the default host to send mail to
# when no entry is matched in the optional transport(5) table. When
# no relayhost is given, mail is routed directly to the destination.
#
# On an intranet, specify the organizational domain name. If your
# internal DNS uses no MX records, specify the name of the intranet
# gateway host instead.
#
# In the case of SMTP, specify a domain, host, host:port, [host]:port,
# [address] or [address]:port; the form [host] turns off MX lookups.
#
# If you're connected via UUCP, see also the default_transport parameter.
#
#relayhost = $mydomain
#relayhost = [gateway.my.domain]
#relayhost = [mailserver.isp.tld]
#relayhost = uucphost
#relayhost = [an.ip.add.ress]

# REJECTING UNKNOWN RELAY USERS
#
# The relay_recipient_maps parameter specifies optional lookup tables
# with all addresses in the domains that match $relay_domains.
#
# If this parameter is defined, then the SMTP server will reject
# mail for unknown relay users. This feature is off by default.
#
# The right-hand side of the lookup tables is conveniently ignored.
# In the left-hand side, specify an @domain.tld wild-card, or specify
# a user@domain.tld address.
# 
#relay_recipient_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_recipients

# INPUT RATE CONTROL
#
# The in_flow_delay configuration parameter implements mail input
# flow control. This feature is turned on by default, although it
# still needs further development (it's disabled on SCO UNIX due
# to an SCO bug).
# 
# A Postfix process will pause for $in_flow_delay seconds before
# accepting a new message, when the message arrival rate exceeds the
# message delivery rate. With the default 100 SMTP server process
# limit, this limits the mail inflow to 100 messages a second more
# than the number of messages delivered per second.
# 
# Specify 0 to disable the feature. Valid delays are 0..10.
# 
#in_flow_delay = 1s

# ADDRESS REWRITING
#
# The ADDRESS_REWRITING_README document gives information about
# address masquerading or other forms of address rewriting including
# username->Firstname.Lastname mapping.

# ADDRESS REDIRECTION (VIRTUAL DOMAIN)
#
# The VIRTUAL_README document gives information about the many forms
# of domain hosting that Postfix supports.

# "USER HAS MOVED" BOUNCE MESSAGES
#
# See the discussion in the ADDRESS_REWRITING_README document.

# TRANSPORT MAP
#
# See the discussion in the ADDRESS_REWRITING_README document.

# ALIAS DATABASE
#
# The alias_maps parameter specifies the list of alias databases used
# by the local delivery agent. The default list is system dependent.
#
# On systems with NIS, the default is to search the local alias
# database, then the NIS alias database. See aliases(5) for syntax
# details.
# 
# If you change the alias database, run "postalias /etc/aliases" (or
# wherever your system stores the mail alias file), or simply run
# "newaliases" to build the necessary DBM or DB file.
#
# It will take a minute or so before changes become visible.  Use
# "postfix reload" to eliminate the delay.
#
#alias_maps = dbm:/etc/aliases
#alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
#alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, nis:mail.aliases
#alias_maps = netinfo:/aliases

# The alias_database parameter specifies the alias database(s) that
# are built with "newaliases" or "sendmail -bi".  This is a separate
# configuration parameter, because alias_maps (see above) may specify
# tables that are not necessarily all under control by Postfix.
#
#alias_database = dbm:/etc/aliases
#alias_database = dbm:/etc/mail/aliases
#alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
#alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/opt/majordomo/aliases

# ADDRESS EXTENSIONS (e.g., user+foo)
#
# The recipient_delimiter parameter specifies the separator between
# user names and address extensions (user+foo). See canonical(5),
# local(8), relocated(5) and virtual(5) for the effects this has on
# aliases, canonical, virtual, relocated and .forward file lookups.
# Basically, the software tries user+foo and .forward+foo before
# trying user and .forward.
#
#recipient_delimiter = +

# DELIVERY TO MAILBOX
#
# The home_mailbox parameter specifies the optional pathname of a
# mailbox file relative to a user's home directory. The default
# mailbox file is /var/spool/mail/user or /var/mail/user.  Specify
# "Maildir/" for qmail-style delivery (the / is required).
#
#home_mailbox = Mailbox
#home_mailbox = Maildir/

# The mail_spool_directory parameter specifies the directory where
# UNIX-style mailboxes are kept. The default setting depends on the
# system type.
#
#mail_spool_directory = /var/mail
#mail_spool_directory = /var/spool/mail

# The mailbox_command parameter specifies the optional external
# command to use instead of mailbox delivery. The command is run as
# the recipient with proper HOME, SHELL and LOGNAME environment settings.
# Exception:  delivery for root is done as $default_user.
#
# Other environment variables of interest: USER (recipient username),
# EXTENSION (address extension), DOMAIN (domain part of address),
# and LOCAL (the address localpart).
#
# Unlike other Postfix configuration parameters, the mailbox_command
# parameter is not subjected to $parameter substitutions. This is to
# make it easier to specify shell syntax (see example below).
#
# Avoid shell meta characters because they will force Postfix to run
# an expensive shell process. Procmail alone is expensive enough.
#
# IF YOU USE THIS TO DELIVER MAIL SYSTEM-WIDE, YOU MUST SET UP AN
# ALIAS THAT FORWARDS MAIL FOR ROOT TO A REAL USER.
#
#mailbox_command = /some/where/procmail
#mailbox_command = /some/where/procmail -a "$EXTENSION"

# The mailbox_transport specifies the optional transport in master.cf
# to use after processing aliases and .forward files. This parameter
# has precedence over the mailbox_command, fallback_transport and
# luser_relay parameters.
#
# Specify a string of the form transport:nexthop, where transport is
# the name of a mail delivery transport defined in master.cf.  The
# :nexthop part is optional. For more details see the sample transport
# configuration file.
#
# NOTE: if you use this feature for accounts not in the UNIX password
# file, then you must update the "local_recipient_maps" setting in
# the main.cf file, otherwise the SMTP server will reject mail for    
# non-UNIX accounts with "User unknown in local recipient table".
#
# Cyrus IMAP over LMTP. Specify ``lmtpunix      cmd="lmtpd"
# listen="/var/imap/socket/lmtp" prefork=0'' in cyrus.conf.
#mailbox_transport = lmtp:unix:/var/imap/socket/lmtp
#
# Cyrus IMAP via command line. Uncomment the "cyrus...pipe" and
# subsequent line in master.cf.
#mailbox_transport = cyrus

# The fallback_transport specifies the optional transport in master.cf
# to use for recipients that are not found in the UNIX passwd database.
# This parameter has precedence over the luser_relay parameter.
#
# Specify a string of the form transport:nexthop, where transport is
# the name of a mail delivery transport defined in master.cf.  The
# :nexthop part is optional. For more details see the sample transport
# configuration file.
#
# NOTE: if you use this feature for accounts not in the UNIX password
# file, then you must update the "local_recipient_maps" setting in
# the main.cf file, otherwise the SMTP server will reject mail for    
# non-UNIX accounts with "User unknown in local recipient table".
#
#fallback_transport = lmtp:unix:/file/name
#fallback_transport = cyrus
#fallback_transport =

# The luser_relay parameter specifies an optional destination address
# for unknown recipients.  By default, mail for unknown@$mydestination,
# unknown@[$inet_interfaces] or unknown@[$proxy_interfaces] is returned
# as undeliverable.
#
# The following expansions are done on luser_relay: $user (recipient
# username), $shell (recipient shell), $home (recipient home directory),
# $recipient (full recipient address), $extension (recipient address
# extension), $domain (recipient domain), $local (entire recipient
# localpart), $recipient_delimiter. Specify ${name?value} or
# ${name:value} to expand value only when $name does (does not) exist.
#
# luser_relay works only for the default Postfix local delivery agent.
#
# NOTE: if you use this feature for accounts not in the UNIX password
# file, then you must specify "local_recipient_maps =" (i.e. empty) in
# the main.cf file, otherwise the SMTP server will reject mail for    
# non-UNIX accounts with "User unknown in local recipient table".
#
#luser_relay = $user@other.host
#luser_relay = $local@other.host
#luser_relay = admin+$local

# JUNK MAIL CONTROLS
# 
# The controls listed here are only a very small subset. The file
# SMTPD_ACCESS_README provides an overview.

# The header_checks parameter specifies an optional table with patterns
# that each logical message header is matched against, including
# headers that span multiple physical lines.
#
# By default, these patterns also apply to MIME headers and to the
# headers of attached messages. With older Postfix versions, MIME and
# attached message headers were treated as body text.
#
# For details, see "man header_checks".
#
#header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks

# FAST ETRN SERVICE
#
# Postfix maintains per-destination logfiles with information about
# deferred mail, so that mail can be flushed quickly with the SMTP
# "ETRN domain.tld" command, or by executing "sendmail -qRdomain.tld".
# See the ETRN_README document for a detailed description.
# 
# The fast_flush_domains parameter controls what destinations are
# eligible for this service. By default, they are all domains that
# this server is willing to relay mail to.
# 
#fast_flush_domains = $relay_domains

# SHOW SOFTWARE VERSION OR NOT
#
# The smtpd_banner parameter specifies the text that follows the 220
# code in the SMTP server's greeting banner. Some people like to see
# the mail version advertised. By default, Postfix shows no version.
#
# You MUST specify $myhostname at the start of the text. That is an
# RFC requirement. Postfix itself does not care.
#
#smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
#smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name ($mail_version)

# PARALLEL DELIVERY TO THE SAME DESTINATION
#
# How many parallel deliveries to the same user or domain? With local
# delivery, it does not make sense to do massively parallel delivery
# to the same user, because mailbox updates must happen sequentially,
# and expensive pipelines in .forward files can cause disasters when
# too many are run at the same time. With SMTP deliveries, 10
# simultaneous connections to the same domain could be sufficient to
# raise eyebrows.
# 
# Each message delivery transport has its XXX_destination_concurrency_limit
# parameter.  The default is $default_destination_concurrency_limit for
# most delivery transports. For the local delivery agent the default is 2.

#local_destination_concurrency_limit = 2
#default_destination_concurrency_limit = 20

# DEBUGGING CONTROL
#
# The debug_peer_level parameter specifies the increment in verbose
# logging level when an SMTP client or server host name or address
# matches a pattern in the debug_peer_list parameter.
#
debug_peer_level = 2

# The debug_peer_list parameter specifies an optional list of domain
# or network patterns, /file/name patterns or type:name tables. When
# an SMTP client or server host name or address matches a pattern,
# increase the verbose logging level by the amount specified in the
# debug_peer_level parameter.
#
#debug_peer_list = 127.0.0.1
#debug_peer_list = some.domain

# The debugger_command specifies the external command that is executed
# when a Postfix daemon program is run with the -D option.
#
# Use "command .. & sleep 5" so that the debugger can attach before
# the process marches on. If you use an X-based debugger, be sure to
# set up your XAUTHORITY environment variable before starting Postfix.
#
debugger_command =
     PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
     ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5

# If you can't use X, use this to capture the call stack when a
# daemon crashes. The result is in a file in the configuration
# directory, and is named after the process name and the process ID.
#
# debugger_command =
#   PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin; export PATH; (echo cont;
#   echo where) | gdb $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id 2>&1
#   >$config_directory/$process_name.$process_id.log & sleep 5
#
# Another possibility is to run gdb under a detached screen session.
# To attach to the screen sesssion, su root and run "screen -r
# <id_string>" where <id_string> uniquely matches one of the detached
# sessions (from "screen -list").
#
# debugger_command =
#   PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin; export PATH; screen
#   -dmS $process_name gdb $daemon_directory/$process_name
#   $process_id & sleep 1

# INSTALL-TIME CONFIGURATION INFORMATION
#
# The following parameters are used when installing a new Postfix version.
# 
# sendmail_path: The full pathname of the Postfix sendmail command.
# This is the Sendmail-compatible mail posting interface.
# 
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail

# newaliases_path: The full pathname of the Postfix newaliases command.
# This is the Sendmail-compatible command to build alias databases.
#
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases

# mailq_path: The full pathname of the Postfix mailq command.  This
# is the Sendmail-compatible mail queue listing command.
# 
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq

# setgid_group: The group for mail submission and queue management
# commands.  This must be a group name with a numerical group ID that
# is not shared with other accounts, not even with the Postfix account.
#
setgid_group = _postdrop

# html_directory: The location of the Postfix HTML documentation.
#
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html

# manpage_directory: The location of the Postfix on-line manual pages.
#
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man

# sample_directory: The location of the Postfix sample configuration files.
# This parameter is obsolete as of Postfix 2.1.
#
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/examples

# readme_directory: The location of the Postfix README files.
#
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
inet_protocols = all
message_size_limit = 10485760
mailbox_size_limit = 0
biff = no
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, [::1]/128
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated permit
recipient_delimiter = +
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
smtpd_tls_ciphers = medium
inet_interfaces = loopback-only

#Gmail SMTP
relayhost=smtp.gmail.com:587
# Enable SASL authentication in the Postfix SMTP client.
smtp_sasl_auth_enable=yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter=plain
# Enable Transport Layer Security (TLS), i.e. SSL.
smtp_use_tls=yes
smtp_tls_security_level=encrypt
tls_random_source=dev:/dev/urandom
```

Comment: What *exactly* did you have to change for it to work?  All I see at a quick glance is the changed `relayhost`.

Comment: `inet_protocols = all
message_size_limit = 10485760
mailbox_size_limit = 0
biff = no
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, [::1]/128
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated permit
recipient_delimiter = +
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
smtpd_tls_ciphers = medium
inet_interfaces = loopback-only`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `relayhost` entry doesn't fit the `sasl_passwd` entry.  Change

```
smtp.gmail.com:465 XXXXXXXXX@gmail.com:XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

to

```
[smtp.gmail.com]:587 XXXXXXXXX@gmail.com:XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

i.e. change the port from smtps to submission and add square brackets around the hostname.  The entry must match `relayhost` verbatim.

If that doesn't help, make sure that `grep '^tlsmgr' /etc/postfix/master.cf` returns a result.  Uncomment any respective line in `master.cf` if the above command fails.

Comment: Changing port didn't help me. And uncommenting tlsmgr too.

Comment: @AlexYeremenko My bad, updated my answer.  If this still fails, could you edit your question and add the full contents of `/etc/postfix/master.cf` and `/etc/postfix/main.cf`?